# Does Microsoft Security Essentials automatically update to version 2?

Tags: windows, ms-security-essentials

I have Microsoft Security Essentials version 1. However it does not seem to be able to update to version 2. Do I have to download MSE v2 to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It did for me, came down via Windows Update after a few days.

Make sure ***Microsoft Update*** is enabled if you use Windows 7

Comment: I have 5 computers with Win7, Vista, and XP. Despite they all have automatic updates enabled, MSE did not get updated to v2 till I manually did it.

Comment: I just now got the upgrade prompt, so it is automatic!

Answer (score 5):

It does not update automatically. You have to download v2 and install it manually by running the exe. You can download v2 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/).